# SQL Function that creates a table of dates

Tags: sql, function, date

This function returns a single date and not a list of 61 dates as expected. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
alter FUNCTION udf_foo()
RETURNS  @Result TABLE
(
days datetime
)

AS
begin
DECLARE @i int = -1
begin
WHILE @i < 60
SET @i = @i + 1
INSERT into @Result select  dateadd (day, -@i, getdate())
end ;
return;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you wrote it, the body of the `WHILE` loop only spans the next statement.

You only get one result because the `INSERT` isn't part of the loop's body and it only executed once (after the loop incremented `@i` to `60`).

If you want to have a body of more than one statement, enclose the statements in a `BEGIN ... END` block.

```
...
WHILE @i < 60
BEGIN
  SET @i = @i + 1;
  INSERT INTO @Result
              SELECT dateadd(day, -@i, getdate());
END;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a CTE for this:

```
with dates as (
      select cast(getdate() as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, -1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate())
     )
select *
from dates;
```

You hardly need a function for this, although you could put this in a function if you really wanted to.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1b789/1) is an example of incorporating this into a view.

Comment: Thank you.  I did see this and it worked well by itself, but when I tried to use it in the view it was not working.  Needed a function to create a table that can be used in another query.

Comment: @Komsinica . . . There is no issue putting this in a view:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1b789/1.

Comment: Ha, I must have done something wrong when I tried to create a view.  Thank you, this is very helpful code.